# Escape special characters in Dataframe Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

Input: a dataframe with special characters: "â€™" in some of the values.

Output: search for this string "â€™" and replace it with "'"

Example: I execute this code but it cannot search for special characters

```
import pandas as pd
df = {"Name": ["abcâ€™ company", "dfeâ€™ company"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
for i in df["Name"]:
   if "â€™" in i:
      j = i.replace("â€™", "'")
      df.replace(to_replace=i, value=j)
```

Comment: Strings like `"â€™"` are the result of bytes being decoded using the wrong encoding.  How did you get this data?

Comment: I use pandas to read data from an excel file which has these characters.

Comment: If the Excel file already has these characters then it's corrupted.  It may be that it was originally encoded as UTF-8, but at some point has been saved with the system default encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Just try pass `regex`

```
df = df.replace({'â€™':"'"}, regex=True)
           Name
0  abc' company
1  dfe' company
```

Comment: It works with this code. But when I apply to replacce the dataframe from a csv file, it cannot. Any idea?